# Does .beeline serve the same purpose as the .hiverc?

Tags: hadoop, jar, hive, beeline

My office is currently transitioning from hive to beeline.

I currently have a .hiverc file that loads some JAR files for me and I would like to transition everything in the .hiverc to beeline if possible.

Currently the only file in my directory that seems relevant is the .beeline (unless I am looking for .beelinerc, haha). Does beeline support what hive supported with the .hiverc file?

.hiverc contents:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;
set hive.variable.substitute=true;
set hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
--set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
set mapreduce.map.output.compress=true;
set mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2048;
set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx4916m;
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx4916m;
set mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=600;
set mapred.reduce.tasks=199;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=false;
set hive.optimize.index.filter=false;
set hive.exec.reducers.max=2999;
set hive.exec.orc.default.buffer.size=131072;
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=64000000;
set hive.exec.orc.default.buffer.size=65536;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
set hive.optimize.index.filter=false;
set fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=false;
--
set mapreduce.job.queuename=Three;
set mapred.job.queue.name=Three;
--add jar hdfs:///user/user_A/esri/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar;
add jar hdfs:///user/user_A/esri/esri-geometry-api.jar;
add jar hdfs:///user/user_A/esri/spatial-sdk-hive-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
add jar hdfs:///user/user_A/esri/spatial-sdk-json-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
source /home/user_A/esri/function-ddl.sql;
add jar /home/edpintdatp/jobs/data_ingestion/thirdpartyjars/json-serde-1.3.1.jar;
add jar hdfs:///user/user_A/esri/brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
source /home/user_A/esri/brickhouse.sql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Jira Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5160) , your `.hiverc` will work with `beeline` as it works with `hive-cli` if your Hive Version is > 0.14.0.

Comment: If that is the case, I must have something messed up, haha. When I initiate the Hive CLI via 'hive', it instantly connects me and puts me in the correct database 'user_A' (seems to have got cut off at the end use user_A;).

When I run beeline, it just puts me in a beeline terminal at which point I have to connect to the hive2 connection via jdbc. I am assuming it may just be a different formatting/commands?

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I got it to work manually, now I just need to find out how to make the file run once you make a connection.

Comment: beeline -i <your init file> should work.  Is it not working?

Comment: After I commented, I searched for ways to run it automatically and that is what I discovered. Thanks for the verification though.

-f also works to a degree, but it closes the connection immediately after running.

Answer (score 1):

Use the beeline command line option -i as shown below for initialization.

```
beeline -i ~/.hiverc -u jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2.com:10000 $USER org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

Refer this wiki [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineCommandOptions)